# Which Python Library to use to open an existing large xlsx?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have used openpyxl with Workbook(write_only=True)  to create large Excel xlsx files. In this mode I cannot format the Excel headers. I then save the xlsx and open it again with openpyxl load_workbook(my_book) and have the ability to format the cells. I then save the file. If the file isn't too large it saves but otherwise gives a memory error.
So Openfile allows me to create and save the worksheet but not necessarily re-open and save the same worksheet.
In this example I just load_workbook then save without changing the xlsx to show the error

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
# then append a lot of rows
logging.info('Save unformatted xlsx')
wb.save(my_book)
workbook = load_workbook(my_book)
# the worksheet always loads ok at this point, even when  700,000 rows
workbook.save(my_book)

## Immediately after load_workbook I do workbook.save(my_book). 
When the rowcount is around 8600 there is no problem. When 350,000 there is a memory error

File "src\lxml\serializer.pxi", line 1268, in lxml.etree._IncrementalFileWriter._handle_error
File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 316, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored
File "src\lxml\serializer.pxi", line 650, in lxml.etree._FilelikeWriter.write
MemoryError


logging.info('Saved unformatted xlsx immediately after opening again')
workbook = load_workbook(my_book)
# If no error I do some formatting and all is well and can save ok
```

Python 3.4.3
openpyxl (2.5.1)
lxml (4.2.1)

There are a lot of solutions for older versions but I cannot see any for openpyxl (2.5.1).
Does anyone have an answer for openpyxl, or can recommend what to use to open an existing large xlsx and format cells?

Comment: Asking for libraries is off topic, but possibly someone can help you with your current code. Please edit your question to ask concrete questions about the problems of your code or open a new question for a library at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As long as the workbook is open you're going to be using a lot of memory and it looks like you don't have enough on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't of topic, it was an error even if just a memory error. Anyway in the end I just exported to CSV rather than XSLX as Excel still opens it nicely, not worth the bother.